# Changing current viewModel in .NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

My View uses the Model like below:

```
public class ObjectViewModel
{
    public int ChosenVariant{ get; set; }
    public List<Object> Objects{ get; set; }
}
```

but on page I am displaying details only of one of `Object` from the list (whose `id` is equal `ChosenVariant`).

On the same page I have radio buttons and each of them is binded to one of the Objects from the list:

```
@foreach (var obj in Model.Objects)
{
<div class="radio">
    @{
        var options = new RouteValueDictionary();
        options["onchange"] = "UpdatePage()";

        if (product.ID == Model.ChosenVariant)
        {
            options["checked"] = "checked";
        }
    }
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => Model.ChosenVariant, @product.ID, options)
</div>
}
```

My problem is that how I can refresh the `Model.ChosenVariant` and render once again page without refresh?

My first idea was returning whole `Model` with new value  of `Model.ChosenVariant` in javascript function (on onchange radio button).
This function will call `Post` action to a Controler, which return once again whole `Model` (but with new changed `Model.ChosenVariant`. Then on `done` action of this Post call I will use  `$(panel).html(data);` for refresh the page.

Is there any easier way to change the current viewmodel without calling Controller?

Comment: Are you familiar with AJAX?

Comment: Yes, but I wondering what is the best practise to handle my problem in connection with .NET MVC.

Comment: Well using MVC alone you can't really load fresh data from the server without reloading the page. You could provide all the models to the page and just use JavaScript to flip between them, but that might be a lot of data. Your best bet is to use AJAX to retrieve the other models from the database.

Comment: @mason But I want to use DB only once, on first page load, then I pass whole ViewModel with i.e. 4 objects. So I should put this 4 objects into parameters for onchange function for every radio button?

Comment: Sure, that could work. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @mason I tried it and it worked, of course, but it is connected with binding a lot of data to each of radio button, and this is what I want to avoid. Therefore I made my post...